# How many ways are there of splitting twelve people into two groups of the same size?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Twelve people need to be split up into teams for a quiz. How many ways are there of splitting them into two groups of the same size?

I did $12 C 6$, which gives $924$, however the answer is $\frac{1}{2}(12 C 6)$, which is $462$. Why is the $12 C 6$ halved?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it depends on whether the teams are **labelled** or **unlabelled**.

Your answer is for labelled teams whereas the book answer is for  unlabelled teams.

For instance, you can divide 1234 as 12|34, 13|24, 14|23, 23|14, 24|13 and 34|13.

But if they are unlabelled teams, **each pair** like 12|34 and 34|12 **are the same.**

The question doesn't say labelled teams (e.g. team A and team B), so we take it as unlabelled teams.

Answer (score 2):

$12\choose 6$ double counts.  For instance you could choose A, B, C, D, E, F for one group, leaving G, H, I, J, K, L for the other; or you could choose G, H, I, J, K, L for one group, leaving A, B, C, D, E. F.  But this actually gives you the same two groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it as such: first of all put these people in one straight line , you can rearrange them in $12!$ ways. The first six from the left to the right is one team, and the other 6 the second one ( you don't have to worry about that). Now you have to fix the fact that you don't want to count multiple times for things like **A B** C D X Y | E F G H Q P and **B A** C D X Y | E F G H Q P (i just changed the order of people A and B) . Once, you compute a possible team as (A ,B ,C,D,X,Y) (E , F , G ,H, Q ,P) make sure you exclude their rearrangements ($6!$ for each). Finally , make sure you don't count twice facts like :E F G H Q P | A B C D X Y (we paired the exact same people ) so divide by $2!$ to fix that . Generally , if you need to separate $n$  people into $r$ teams with $n_1, n_2, .., n_r$ people each $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!...n_r}$. As mentioned above and as stated in your problem : if teams are not "labeled" - we only care which people pair with which- then those "created " teams have $r!$ rearrangements so divide by this and $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!...n_r*r!}$ and you are done.